# Are nullhomotopic maps trivial in $Set$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $F$ a contravariant functor $F: Ho(Top) \to Set$. Let $f$ a morphism in $Ho(Top)$ such that $f$ is nullhomotopic, which means that $F(f) = F(c)$, where $c$ is the constant map. Knowing that $F(\left\{x_0 \right\})$ is a one element set, does this imply that $F(f) = 0$? Why?

Comment: Whats $0$ here? $\mathbf{Set}$ doesn't have a zero object.

Comment: $0$ is the null map

Comment: Since $c$ factors through a one-point space, $F(c)$ factors through a one-element set by the hypothesis, so it must be a constant map.

Comment: My question is what the "null map in $\mathbf{Set}$" explicitly is. Zero morphisms in categories with zero objects make sense, but $\mathbf{Set}$ isn't a category with zero objects, so this is some non-standard notion.

Comment: I am actually talking about a small result on Hatcher at page 449, in the chapter dedicated to Brown theorem. The map is an inclusion of a CW complex in a contractible one, so the map is nullhomotopic. He concludes that the induced map through the functor factors through $F(point)$, which is misteriously said to be zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the assumptions of Hatcher 4E.2 it is said that the codomain of $h$ is the category of **pointed** sets; this category has a zero object (=initial and terminal), the (or rather, any) singleton.

Evidently, all cohomology theories are functors to (families of) pointed sets: $h^n(A)$ are abelian groups! (-;

RE the comment: yes, in principle, yes. The notation may vary (a matter of taste I guess?), but the idea is that there is a unique arrow $A \to 0 \to B$ obtained composing the terminal arrow of $A$ and the initial arrow of $B$. This map exists in every category with a zero object, and it is "constant at the basepoint of $B$".

This said, the category of pointed sets behaves in many ways like the category of pointed *spaces*, for example it supports a smash product structure obtained from the pushout
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
A\vee B @>>> A \times B \\ 
@VVV @VVV \\
0 @>>> A\land B
\end{CD}
$$
rendering ${\sf Set}_*$ a monoidal closed category (beware, yet, that the smash product is *not* the product: instead, the above pushout is telling you that it measures how far are coproducts and products from being equal: the bigger $A\land B$, the further), and it sits in an adjunction
$$
(-)_+ : {\sf Set} \leftrightarrows {\sf Set}_* : U
$$
rendering the category of pointed sets the category of algebras for a monad on $\sf Set$ (this is a monad of interest for functional programmers, who call it "Maybe": it takes a set $X$ and gives you back a new set $X_+$ with a disjoint point $\bullet$). But these many similarities shouldn't trick you into believing that everything that holds true for pointed spaces transports to pointed sets.

Comment: Zooming in: whenever I read a $0$ referred to a morphism in the category of pointed sets, I can infer that it is a constant map, correct?

Comment: Yes, I name-dropped a few facts in the answer for better reference!

Comment: Many thanks! :)